# Why does the color of text change in a transparent DIV tag?

Tags: css

Hi Can you please take a look at following examole(code and link) and let me know why the color of the other elements inside a transparent div also change and how I can prevent this? I mean I like ti have the textbox and font color in white as I specified already but now they look grey!

[Here is the link](http://ghazalphoto.com/contact/)

As you can see from the link the text an inputs color inside the boxes changed to grey!
and this the code:

```
.test
{
    color:#FFF;
    border: solid 2px #2d2d2d;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 180px;
    width: 250px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.60;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `opacity` on an element will affect all child elements as well. That's the reason for why your text looks grey. To prevent this use a RGBA-color and set at the same time it's transparency value.

I created a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShSMW/1/) that shows the differences.

And here's  the code for the `background`.

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* The last value declares the transparency */
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Christopher, This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The white turns to grey because you are setting the opacity of something with to 60% over a black background.  Remove the opacity rules and it should look like you are expecting.

**Remove these CSS rules**

```
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity: 0.60;
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your comment but my question is also how to stop this AND keeping the box transparency as well.I mean I don't want to remove  the transparency